# Filtering Rows in F#

Tags: f#, deedle

I have a code where I have the following frame and filter rows as follows:

```
let dfff= 
[ "year" => series [ 1 => 1990.0; 2 => 1991.00; 3 => 1992.0;  4 => 1993.0]
  "gold"  => series [ 1 => 10.0; 2 => 10.00; 3 => 15.0; 4 => 20.0] 
  "silver"  => series [ 1 => 20.0; 2 => 30.00; 3 => 45.0; 4 => 55.0] ] 
|> frame

let dfff2 = dfff |> Frame.filterRows (fun key row  -> row?year <= 1992.0 )
```

Why do I have to write key in

```
Frame.filterRows (fun key row  -> row?year <= 1992.0)
```

if my function only depends on row? What role does key play here? I will appreciate if anybody could explain me the logic. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Deedle, frames have row keys and column keys. In your case, you have `Frame<int, string>` meaning that the row keys are integers (just numbers) and column keys are strings (column names) - but you might also have dates or other more interesting things as row keys.

The `filterRows` function gives you the row key together with row data. The `key` parameter is just the row key - in your case, this is (uninteresting) int index, but it might be e.g. useful date in other scenarios.

F# lets you write `_` to explicitly ignore the value:

```
let dfff2 = dfff |> Frame.filterRows (fun _ row  -> row?year <= 1992.0 )
```

In the `Series` module, we have `Series.filter` and `Series.filterValues` where the first one gives you key & value and the second one gives you just the value. So, we could follow the same pattern and add `Frame.filterRowValues`.

This would actually be quite easy, so if you want to contribute, please send a pull request with a change somewhere [around here](https://github.com/BlueMountainCapital/Deedle/blob/master/src/Deedle/FrameModule.fs#L950) :-).